# Unit test for attribute fails, only meant to be run on a single node?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using Enzyme and Jest to check that a dropdown list has an `id` attribute.

```
import React from "react";
import { mount } from "enzyme";
import ListPicker from './ListPicker.js'

describe("ListPicker", () => {
  let props;
  let mountedListPicker;
  const labelText = "label";
  const idName = "id";
  const wrapper = () => {
    if (!mountedListPicker) {
      mountedListPicker = mount(
        <ListPicker label={labelText} id={idName} {...props} data-component="ListPicker">
          <option value="USA">United States</option>
          [...]
        </ListPicker>
      );
    }
    return mountedListPicker;
  };

  beforeEach(() => {
    props = {
        id: undefined
    };

    mountedListPicker = undefined;
  });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

```
 it("has an id attribute", () => {
    const idName = wrapper().find("id");
    expect(idName.prop()).toBe(idName);
  });
```

The test output says "Method “props” is only meant to be run on a single node. 0 found instead."

Answer (score 1):

[`find`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/find.html) takes a selector and returns a `ReactWrapper` for the found node(s).

[`prop`](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/prop.html) takes the prop name as an argument and returns the prop value.

---

To select by `id` you would use [a CSS selector](https://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/selector.html#1-a-valid-css-selector) like this: `.find('#id')`

To get the `id` property value you would use `.prop('id')`

Here's a simple example:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';

test('simple test', () => {
  const wrapper = mount(<div id='outer'><div id='inner'>content</div></div>);

  expect(wrapper.prop('id')).toBe('outer'); // Success!

  const innerDivWrapper = wrapper.find('#inner');
  expect(innerDivWrapper.prop('id')).toBe('inner');  // Success!
})
```

Comment: Thank you @brian-lives-outdoors - this didn't work for me, and I'm not sure why. I'm getting the same error. Maybe I can clarify in another comment once I get it sorted. Thank you so much for your comment, it is very helpful even though I couldn't get it to work in this particular instance!

Comment: It's possible the element you are looking for isn't rendered, you can do `console.log(mountedListPicker.html());` to see if it exists in the rendered output @bunnycode